# javascript return data after success function

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql, ajax, codeigniter

I want to submit a form using ajax function to mysql, but my attempt gives me the NULL results in mysql table.

Here's my javascript :

```js
function pesan()
    { 
        email = $("#email").val(); 
        from_nama = $("#from_nama").val(); 
        from_phone = $("#from_phone").val(); 

        $.ajax
        ({
            url : "<?php echo site_url('kirim/undangan')?>/",
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "JSON",
            success: function(data)
            {       
               $('#alert').show();
               $('#email'+data).html(data.email);
               $('#from_nama'+data).html(data.from_nama);
               $('#from_phone'+data).html(data.from_phone);
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
            {
                alert('Error upload data');
            }

        });
    }
```

And the form :

```html
        <h4 id="form">Data Personal</h4>

                            <div class="col-sm-4">
                                <input type="email" class="form-control input-lg" id="email"  name="email"  placeholder="Email" required>
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-sm-4">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg"  id="from_nama" name="from_nama" placeholder="Nama" required>
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-sm-4">
                                <input type="number" class="form-control input-lg"  id="from_phone"  name="from_phone" placeholder="Phone" required>
                            </div>
                            <div>
                               <input type="hidden" name="id" id="id" />
                            </div>
                            <br>
                            <div class="row" align="center">
                                
                                    <button id="pesan" type="button" class="btn btn-download btn-md" onclick=pesan()>
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-send" aria-hidden="true" ></span>
                                    Pesan
                                    </button>
```

Here's the controller :

```html
function undangan()
 { 
   $email          =   $this->input->post('email');
   $from_nama  =   $this->input->post('from_nama');
   $from_phone  =   $this->input->post('from_phone');

   $data_user = array(

    'email'        => $email,
    'name'            => $from_nama,
    'phone'        => $from_phone,
    'status'                => '0',
    'unique_id'            => uniqid()

       );

            $this->load->model('excel');
            
   $this->excel->tambahuser($data_user);
       
    
  $this->load->view('kirimundangan.php',$data);
 }
```

The model :

```html
function tambahuser($data_user)
        {
            $this->db->insert('request', $data_user);
            $this->db->insert_id();
            
            foreach ($data_user as $key)     
            {  
                $data = array(
                    
                    'from_name'          =>   $this->input->post('from_nama'),
                    'from_phone'         =>   $this->input->post('from_phone')
                );
            }
             
        }
```

I think I made mistake in writing code inside the success:function(data), any help?

Comment: you are not sending email , from_nama, from_phone to ajax? thats why nothing is saving in DB and add your server side code

Comment: i try the code above but it gives me NULL to every field in the table :(

Comment: you mean email = $("#email").val() eq to null ? when you add alert on java script ? and add server side code

Comment: here u write code is wrong `$this->load->view('kirimundangan.php',$data);`

Comment: are u want to  display view in AJAX

Comment: what it should be?

Comment: You need to feed data to a `post` request which is missing in your snippet. Pass the values of `email`, `from_nama` and `from_phone` in ajax call as in additional `data` property.

Comment: if u pass ur view in ajax that u should be write like `$this->load->view('kirimundangan','$data',TRUE)

Comment: i want to upload the value from input text to database @MayankVadiya..

Comment: what am i missing and where should I add it? @Rohit416

Comment: Take a look at the answer @Thorin gave.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change peson function to

```
function pesan()
    { 
        var email = $("#email").val(),
          from_nama = $("#from_nama").val(),
          from_phone = $("#from_phone").val(); 

        $.ajax
        ({
            url : "<?php echo site_url('kirim/undangan')?>/",
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "JSON",
            data:{from_nama: from_nama, email: email, from_phone: from_phone},
            success: function(data)
            {       
               $('#alert').show();
               $('#email'+data).html(data.email);
               $('#from_nama'+data).html(data.from_nama);
               $('#from_phone'+data).html(data.from_phone);
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
            {
                alert('Error upload data');
            }

        });
    }
```

and you expecting a json response so you have to change your server side code as well and from there you have to return data with json not with a view.
I hope this will work for you

Comment: now the data uploaded into database, but why I get the error alert?

Comment: you have to return data with json like $json = json_encode($data); then echo $json;

Comment: inside success function? or controller?

Comment: i remove the json type.. it works fine now. thank you for your help :)

Comment: Actually `jQuery` detects the `datatype` with an intelligent guess if not defined explicitly. So in some situations it is good to omit it.